# Android - Can't find the reason for NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, xml, nullpointerexception, sinch

I am trying to integrate Sinch video calling into my app, so I just copied all those Activities and Layouts from the [Sinch Video-Call Demo App](https://github.com/sinch/android-video-calling/tree/master/res) and it worked fine. Now I am trying to remove the `LoginActivity` so that a call establishes using a default, hard-coded `userName` instead of getting it from an `EditText`. And I only made changes to the `LoginActivity.java` and `login.xml` layout files.

But now, as soon as that Activity launches, it crashes with this error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.yankee.cw/com.example.yankee.cw.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2462)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2522)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5471)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
```

But nowhere in the whole code there is a `setEnabled` called on any `Button` object. Here is a link to the original layout file [`login.xml`](https://github.com/sinch/android-video-calling/blob/master/res/layout/login.xml). And here is mine [`login.xml`](https://gist.github.com/gamebusterz/8ab684c5706d9d64c6767a1d880a2012). Original[`LoginActivity.java`](https://github.com/sinch/android-video-calling/blob/master/src/com/sinch/android/rtc/sample/video/LoginActivity.java) and mine [`LoginActivity.java`](https://gist.github.com/gamebusterz/fb1ba3b9fd18f733b2cc55177e217758)

I am sorry this might seem like a stupid question but I have tried everything I could in the code for the last 5 hours and I still couldn't find what is causing the problem because there is no call to `setEnabled` anywhere in the entire code. Thank you.

Comment: `Line Number 28 & 39` do have calls to `loginButton.setEnabled(booleanVal)`. However, `Line Number 39` in `LoginActivity.java` is most likely to emit `NullPointerException`. Either initialize it there or place a `if(loginButton != null)` condition before hand.

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is that you're NOT using your LoginActivity, but the original one. Check your `import` statements carefully.

Comment: @RishabhDuttSharma You are talking about the original LoginActivity.java , mine has those lines commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your modifications and the base repository of the project in question I think the reason for the `NullPointerException` is the following:

After starting your `LoginActivity` it immediately follows the execution with `LoginActivity#loginClicked()` which starts the next activity rights away

```
private void openPlaceCallActivity() {
    Intent mainActivity = new Intent(this, PlaceCallActivity.class);
    startActivity(mainActivity);
}
```

*... at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity ...*

The `PlaceCallActivity` extends `BaseActivity` which modifies the service lifecycle thus maybe calling the `PlaceCallActivity#onServiceConnected` before `PlaceCallActivity#onCreate`... which coincidentally may have a not initialized `mCallButton`

**PlaceCallActivity#onServiceConnected**

```
    @Override
        protected void onServiceConnected() {
            TextView userName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loggedInName);
            userName.setText(getSinchServiceInterface().getUserName());
            mCallButton.setEnabled(true);  // <--- might try changing this?
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan. Although I used Double Shift to search for all occurrences of `setEnabled` , but it didn't show me any other than those from the definition of the Android classes. This does get rid of the error, but now I am back to another error which I was facing. But let me try to solve it this way first. Thanks again.